# Нужно ли считать «один за одним» просторечием?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Интересно, почему  современной нормой стало выражение «один за другим», мы же говорим «один к одному, одно к одному, один на один», такой повтор не чужд нашей речи?
И у классиков встречается  форма «один за одним», да и современные авторы также ее используют.

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Один за одним, один за одним… с рожками, в пиджачках… мал мала меньше…" (И. А. Бунин).

"Один за одним торопливо спускались по веревочному трапу двадцать четыре гребца, прыгали в качающуюся у борта большую шлюпку и рассаживались по банкам" (К. М. Станюкович).

"Усталые лошади фыркали, люди один за одним соскакивали в грязь" (И. C. Тургенев).

"В полях один за одним, как пузырьки в воде, вспырскивали с чувыканьем жаворонки" (Л. Н. Толстой).

Может быть, здесь дело не только в стиле, но и в разных оттенках смысла. Допустим, «один за одним» – эта форма передает значение монотонности действия или одинаковости предметов, а «один за другим» – это просто их последовательность. Или, может быть, есть другое различие? И может быть, надо внимательнее и бережнее относится к родному языку и не спешить с выводами о неправильности и ненужности речевых оборотов? А как считает вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К выражению "один за одним" я отношусь нейтрально, и если встречу его в литературном тексте, то сочту либо диалектным, либо декоративным (да, пожалуй, в примерах с Буниным и Толстым можно отметить оттенок умилительного единообразия в сменяющихся сущностях), либо устаревшим. Употреблять его повседневно мне не хочется по той же причине, по которой люди не говорят словами, встречающимися только в поэтических текстах. Из похожих выражений как просторечие воспринимаю "один в один" (вместо "один к одному").

А вот обсуждавшееся вместе с этим выражение "все из них" вызывает у меня внутренний протест. Аналогично обстоит с выражениями "ты один из нас" (свой, наш товарищ) или "я являюсь частью проекта" (участвую) - как правило, это приходит из буквальных переводов с чужого языка.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. (Выражение "все из них" я не стала бы здесь обсуждать, так как писатели используют его только при отрицании: не все из них"). Кстати, я говорю "один за другим", "все они", "не все они" и никого не призываю изъясняться  по-другому. Мы говорим так, как слышим, как привыкли, как требует этого окружающая среда. Мне просто интересно, как складываются нормы, не теряем ли мы что-то при этом. Поэтому такой вопрос: в чем вы видите грамматическое нарушение в "один за одним"? И разной семантики вы в двух этих сочетаниях тоже не видите?

Comment: Просто я с детства не слышу этого варианта в повседневной речи, мне это непривычно. Если говорить о буквальном смысле, то, называя разными словами первое и следующее за ним второе, их невозможно спутать. Не возникает вопроса, почему нечто "само за собой следует" - возможно, отсюда впечатление большей точности и быстрой доходчивости пары "одно/другое".

Comment: Другой - не такой.  Мы как бы это утверждаем, а хотели бы сказать: один и еще такой же. Из словаря: ДРУГОЙ. 1.Не этот, не данный. 2.Противоположный 3.Не такой, как этот (или прежний); иной. 4.Второй, следующий. Обратите внимание: нужный смысл только в ЧЕТВЕРТОМ значении! Есть основание задуматься НАД ТОЧНОСТЬЮ выражения.

Comment: Думаю, здесь действует первый смысл: "не тот же самый" (= не данный, а ещё один). Он потому делает здесь слово ясным, что близок к философской категории "различие" - в противоположность "тождеству", к которому клонит "клонированный один". Не возникает мимолётной иллюзии следования "одного" за самим собой. Это у литератора бывает интерес замедлить ход мысли читателя, чтобы он полюбовался его слогом, а в обычной речи запутывать собеседника - непрактично.

Comment: Второе значение ("не такой по свойствам") важно для самого слова, но не в выражении "один за другим" (разные напасти могут следовать одна за другой - то засуха, то потоп). А вот смысл "следования" не присущ самому слову (у нас он выражен предлогом "за"), как и "противоположность" (частный случай отличия свойств) - значения 2 и 4 выведены из сравнительно узкоконтекстных смыслов.

Answer (score 2):

Я давно обратил внимание на то, что в известной песне "Жить стало лучше, жить стало веселей" выражение "одна за одной" лучше ложится на рифму, чем "одна за другой". Тем не менее, ещё в 1936 году написали именно так:

Зво́нки как птицы, одна за другой,

Песни летят над советской страной.

Весел напев городов и полей —

Жить стало лучше, жить стало веселей!

Comment: Да, интересно, "одна за одной" - и рифма точная, и поэтичности больше.

Comment: Улучшение рифмы в первой паре строк могло означать и противопоставление второй паре, где явно нарушен ритм - в последней строке нельзя было укоротить цитату (1935 г.) из речи руководителя страны. 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Жить_стало_лучше,_жить_стало_веселее

Сейчас трудно поверить в такое, но я читал о случае, когда пострадал поэт, зарифмовавший конец строки "... из развалин" (страну поднимали после войны) с фамилией этого руководителя.

Comment: В данном случае это не верно. Размер первых 2-х строк (по 10 слогов)одинаков во всех куплетах этой песни, а строчку "Жить стало лучше, жить стало веселей!" можно считать рефреном, т.к. она присутствует в конце каждого куплета.

Answer (score 1):

Как считаешь ТЫ - разницы нет. Ты же не словарь составляешь.

один за другим - о том, что входят по очереди.
один за одним - входят по-одному.